# Designing an API to work on JSON payload , should Content-type be made mandatory?

Tags: rest, design-patterns

While designing an API , I have defined the contract using **Open API 3.0**

This API has a single endpoint ( POST ) which will receive **JSON payload**

Now as part of design / best practices : should I define the '**Content-type**' header as mandatory with a fixed value of **application/json** in OpenAPI spec ?

Does this look ok or is this considered poor design ?

Comment: This is a very good idea. It's even better to define your own content-type. Sometimes you might want to evolve your API later and one way to introduce breaking changes is by changing the content-type. This will be easier to do if you forced clients to correctly set this header from the beginning.

Comment: What if to that single API endpoint , one need to POST a very large object ? In your case it may not be applicable, but Open API supports other content-types as well, see [reference](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#special-considerations-for-multipart-content)