# Designing an API OpenAPI 3.0 - header parameter Content type are ignored

Tags: api, rest, swagger, mule, openapi

This question is really a followup to an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898215/designing-an-api-to-work-on-json-payload-should-content-type-be-made-mandatory)

what I am trying to do is force the consumer of my api to **ONLY** send *Content-Type* as **application/json**

My environment is : Mule 4.4 runtime ( on prem , no usage of Anypoint Platform )
I am defining the spec in OAS 3.0 and am using swagger editor to create and edit specification

I have the following defined :

```
/user:
post:
  parameters:
    - in: header
      name: Content-Type
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        enum:
          - application/json
```

and I can see a warning:

> Header Parameters named 'Content-type' are ignored. The values for the 'Content-Type' header are defined by 'RequestBody.content.media-type

Tried googling and found one link [here](https://apisecurity.io/encyclopedia/content/oasv3/oasconformance/bestpractices/v3-warning-parameter-header-content-type) But it simply states :

> Make sure that you do not use the restricted values as header parameter names.

which really does not explain of how to enforce this criteria ?

As a side note - if I copy paste the same api spec in Design centre ( Anypoint platform ) it does not complain and infact mule runtime correctly validates and rejects requests that do not have application/json in content-type

Thanks

Comment: on googling further found this page : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5567 , does it mean that if the request body defines the content-type then the header definition is not required and hence swagger is complaining about it ? I somehow feel an explicit statement is better than an implicit one , but that is just me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenAPI (or even RAML) we don't treat the Content-Type header as a generic HTTP header. This applies to both [requests](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/) and [responses](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/). As part of the specification you can define the media types for each request. The implementation will take care of processing it correctly and validate the right Content-Type header is used at execution time. Since you are trying to set it manually the implementation is giving you an expected warning.

Example:

```yaml
paths:
  /services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:        
          application/json:
```

Comment: thanks makes sense